# Byte to Binary String

Tags: binary, byte

I need to convert an 8-bit byte of 1's and 0's to a string reading the same thing.  This is what I have

```
string binstring(byte N) { 
string sN(8,'0');
int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
temp = (N >> i);
if ((temp%2) == '0') {sN[i] = 0;}
else {sN[i] = 1;}
}
return sN + '0';
}
```

My problem is the conversion is not happening.  Nothing is being outputted.

Comment: I assume this is in Java?

Comment: What library are you getting the byte class from?

Comment: I think it's just programmed in the .cpp file somewhere.  We are editing a file our professor gave us.

Comment: I need code for the `byte` class. Does it have an `getInteger` method, a public `integer` variable, or something equivalent?